# Json data search from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

My MySQL table contain json column `academics`.

Table values look like this :

```
id      academics
--------------------------------------------------------
100     ["CBSE-Afternoon-12-A","CBSE-Morning-12-B"]
200     ["CBSE-Afternoon-12-C","CBSE-Morning-12-D"]
300     ["CBSE-Afternoon-12-E","CBSE-Afternoon-12-F"]
```

I have to find the id from the above table based on the search key:

```
CBSE-Morning-12 & CBSE-Afternoon-12
```

I have tried the below query

```
SELECT id 
FROM ACADEMIC_TABLE 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(academics, 'all', 'CBSE-Morning-12%') IS NOT NULL
```

it returns id: 100,200  correctly.

But I need to search with two keywords like condition in JSON
`[CBSE-Morning-12 & CBSE-Afternoon-12 ]` and return id 100,200,300

Please help me

Comment: Thanks, Akina . it work fine...sorry my question is wrong , I have updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to search with two keywords like condition in JSON [CBSE-Morning-12 & CBSE-Afternoon-12 ] and return id 100,200,300

Looking at the sample data - you need the value contained either first or second pattern. If so then you must use `OR`:

```
SELECT id 
FROM ACADEMIC_TEBLE 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(academics, 'one', 'CBSE-Morning-12%') IS NOT NULL
   OR JSON_SEARCH(academics, 'one', 'CBSE-Afternoon-12%') IS NOT NULL;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bdc058111adf7d4200a1471c9873e94c